# Is it possible to test rc0.d scripts without actually restarting the node?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to test rc0.d scripts without actually restarting the node? I don't mean the text of the script but rather will it be called or not? I found out that the script needs to start with K to be invoked on shut down but want to test other such issues.

Comment: I'm going to recommend a VM for this one. That would allow you to test start / restart / shutdown as much as you want, including the scripts.

Comment: Actually I found I can just test at a higher level i.e. 3 or 4 which works in more or less the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On RedHat based Linux systems, run: chkconfig --list to see each service and whether they are enabled or disabled at each run level.

For newer Ubuntu systems (and may be Debian), use: 
service --status-all